# Installing OS X Mavericks to OS X Show Leopard 10.6.8

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks

I have downloaded "Install OS X Mavericks.app" from torrent because of slow and unstable internet connection. Now I am trying to run it:

```
$ open Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Users/john/Downloads/Install OS X Mavericks.app.
```

Trying to run manually:

```
$ ./Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app/Contents/MacOS/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks 
-bash: ./Install OS X Mavericks.app/Contents/MacOS/Install OS X Mavericks: Malformed Mach-o file
```

Trying to create installation media:

```
$ sudo Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia 
sudo: unable to execute Install OS X Mavericks.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia: Malformed Mach-o file
```

Also:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-10M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

Comment: You could just try downloading the installer again from App Store. It took me about 5 attempts to complete the download with a 4G Internet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you have restored your OS X copy from a backup? Well, it seems that this happens because:

*The LSOpenURLsWithRole is a function that is used to associate a file with a program. The file you're double clicking on is not actually an application, but a data file.*

Thanks a lot to @Merlin069 (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/130587/lsopenurlswithrole-failed-with-error-10810-downloaded-app-does-not-start).

I have a copy of OS X that was saved some months ago, copied to my Ubuntu and directly transfered into my OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.8, from an EXT-4 partition. So I thought that the execution permission was disabled on the Darwin binary. Using my old friend **chmod**, my installer was eventually fixed:

> $ chmod +x ./Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app/Contents/MacOS/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks

I know it's too late to answer, but I thought it could be useful for other people. Have a nice day! :)